# Convert CSV file with values spareted in comma to multi columns CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to create a small program to convert a CSV file with one column containing values separated by comma, to CSV file containing multiple columns with one value:

input file:

[image: input file]

output file:

[image: output file]

Therefor I write this code:

```
my_string1 = 'A,B,C,D,E'
my_string2 = 'A,B,C,D,E'
my_string3 = 'A,B,C,D,E'
my_list1 = my_string1.split(",")
my_list2 = my_string2.split(",")
my_list3 = my_string3.split(",")
path = 'C:\Dokumente\\n_1.csv'
rows = zip(my_list1,my_list2,my_list3)
with open(path, "wb") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in rows:
        for column in row:
            writer.writerow('%s;' % column)
```

But the problem is that it writes all the values in one Column.

I want to write column by column and then I want to move to second row to write again?

I work with Eclipse Oxy with PyDev and Python 2.7

Comment: Your problem is that excel or whatever spreadsheet program, you are using is not considering comma/semi-colon as the delimiter. See https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files for help on setting the delimiter

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I dont have an error and the program runs very well but it write all the values in one Column and that what i dont want becouse what i want is to write each value in sparted String in one Column

Comment: @DoctorDoom Yeah, you're right. I was using Python 3 which gave a different result. I have updated my answer for use with Python 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. Firstly, there is no need to use `zip()`, instead you should create a list of lists by simply `rows = [my_list1,my_list2,my_list3]`. The difference between the two can be seen by printing the result:

```
rows_zip = zip(my_list1,my_list2,my_list3)
rows_list = [my_list1,my_list2,my_list3]

print (list(rows_zip))
#[('A', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C'), ('D', 'D', 'D'), ('E', 'E', 'E')]

print (rows_list)
#[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]
```

Secondly, you need to pass the whole list `my_list1` into `writer.writerow()` as this writes the whole row of the csv file. Therefore, you only need one loop, which iterates through your list of lists:

```
my_string1 = 'A,B,C,D,E'
my_string2 = 'A,B,C,D,E'
my_string3 = 'A,B,C,D,E'
my_list1 = my_string1.split(",")
my_list2 = my_string2.split(",")
my_list3 = my_string3.split(",")

path = 'C:\Dokumente\\n_1.csv'
rows = [my_list1,my_list2,my_list3]

with open(path, "wb") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: First of all Thank you very much to correct my code that was great Second i have try what you suggested but also i get the same result CSV file in one Column Can you please try this code with your SAME Enviroment to know if the problem from the code or there are Aconfigration must i do with MS Exel 2016

Comment: If you copy and paste the **exact** code above does this still produce a csv file with one column? This works for me in Python 2.7, although I am using windows 10.

Comment: Ok I think there are a Configration i must do it in My Operating System Thank you Alot

Answer (score 0):

save it as an excel file, CSV is by definition one column separated by commas, colons, etc. In your code you are splitting a string, and then writing them again separating by commas, undoing what you just did before.

You could just use pandas, load the CSV file and save it to excel format

```
    df=pandas.read_csv("file.csv")
    df.to_excel(filename)
```

Comment: i get this error  : Undefined variable: pandas what is the import for it ??

Comment: you'll need to install pandas and then "import pandas"